# Defining all variables as real and positive before differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'm attempting to differentiate an equation in the form

```
D[sqrt((2*(((a*b*c+Pi*d*e^2+Pi*f*g^2+h*i*j+Pi*k*l^2)/(a*b*c+Pi*d*e^2+Pi*f*g^2))-1)*m)/(n^2 - o^2)/p), a]
```

in order to do an error propagation analysis. So I need to differentiate it against a, against b, against c and so on.

All my values will be positive (they reflect physical dimensions of my design) and the value of n will always be greater than o.

Is there a way to define all my variables as real and positive before I differentiate? And to define n greater than o?

The best I've found is $Assumptions = _Symbol [Element] Reals but this only gets me part of the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
assume = (And @@ 
     Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p} > 0]) && n > o;
```

Note that when you state that a variable is positive then it is automatically also real. And for [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) or [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) to have an effect, you must use a function that takes the option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) (e.g., [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)).

```
Assuming[assume, Element[a, Reals] // Simplify]

(* True *)

expr = Assuming[assume, 
  D[Sqrt[(2*(((a*b*c + Pi*d*e^2 + Pi*f*g^2 + h*i*j + Pi*k*l^2)/(a*b*c + 
               Pi*d*e^2 + Pi*f*g^2)) - 1)*m)/(n^2 - o^2)/p], a] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is making the assumption that a is Real and positive, and then it calculates the derivative. But the result is zero.

```
Assuming[ a \[Element] Reals && a > 0, 
 D[sqrt ((2*(((abc + Pide^2 + Pifg^2 + hij + Pikl^2)/(abc + Pide^2 + 
              Pifg^2)) - 1)*m)/(n^2 - o^2)/p), a]]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I think your approach might work for me. I modified my equation to give the following....do you think this makes sense? `Assuming[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p} \[Element] 
   Reals && {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p} > 0, 
 D[((2*(((a*b*c + Pi*d*e^2 + Pi*f*g^2 + h*i*j + Pi*k*l^2)/(a*b*c + 
              Pi*d*e^2 + Pi*f*g^2)) - 1)*m)/(n^2 - o^2)/p)^0.5, a]]`

Comment: Hi @DeltaJ I think it would do the trick. If not, then you can use the following.
a \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && b \[Element] Reals && b > 0 and so on for the rest of the letters.

Hope this helps. Cheers!!!

Comment: Appreciate it thank you ;-)